# How to pipe an entire script to gnuplot?

Tags: lua, pipe, gnuplot

I'm writing a simple binding to gnuplot in Lua. In Lua, I can execute commands in system shell with `execute` and pipe data to gnuplot with `popen` which behave pretty much like in C language. The problem with the latter function is that I can either read from that pipe or write to it. I can open this pipe in 'write' mode and write an entire script line by line, but I will not be able to read from gnuplot stdout which I would like to do. The reason I want to do it is that I can read, for example, an entire png picture as a byte array and pass it to another module to be displayed. I would like to use only pipes and avoid creating temporary files.

I know that I can pass commands through command line to gnuplot with `-e` flag, but it seems I can't put datablocks in here. I'm looking for a way to somehow pipe an entire script to gnuplot, both commands and datablocks. Just like I would execute it from a file.

I'm doing all this on Windows 10 with cmd shell
and I'd like to stick to utilities that are available in my OS  so my script remains portable, but I have access to ported GNU coreutils and GNU shell.

Upd. `echo plot x | gnuplot` allows me to pipe commands to gnuplot. But I can't figure out how to pipe a [datablock](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc3709.html). A datablock is created like this:

```
$Mydata << EOD
     11 22 33
     44 55 66
     77 88 99
     EOD
```

Rows must be separated with a new line, but it seems I cannot print new line symbol with `echo` command.

Comment: You can pass the name of a script containing commands to `gnuplot` using `gnuplot script.plt` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MarkSetchell this will require from me to create such script. I don't want to create a file, I have this script as a string in my program and I want to pipe it directly to gnuplot without storing it somewhere else

Comment: It seems it will read from `stdin` if you want to pipe stuff in. For example `echo "print 'hello'" | gnuplot -`

Comment: @MarkSetchell huh that works to my surprise... In cmd, `echo plot x**2 | gnuplot` does indeed plot y=x^2, but I still cannot pipe data to gnuplot

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the very simplest thing with data that doesn't work.

Comment: You can print a newline with `echo` if you add the `-e` flag to interpret escape sequences, i.e. `echo -en '\n'` Better still though, use `printf "%d %d\n" $v1 $v2` as it will reuse the format string as much as necessary.

Comment: @MarkSetchell this flag does not work in Windows, but it seems I'm out of options and will have to use GNU utils.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `echo` anyway. I thought you had your `gnuplot` commands inside a string in Lua and you wanted to start a subprocess. So why are you trying to use CMD32.EXE's `echo`? Why don't you build the command you want `gnuplot` to run by building it within Lua?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I apologize for my confusing explanations. I have my commands in a string, but if this string has newline symbols in it, I can't pipe it to gnuplot because cmd stops processing my command when it meets a new line. I could separate my commands with `;` symbol and use it like that: `gnuplot -e "set something; plot x"`, but I can't insert a datablock into such string without using newline symbols. And when I run a subprocess, Lua basically uses C function `system` that uses command processor which on Windows is cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from Mark Setchell, I found a way to build the script in the command line and pipe it to gnuplot splitting lines with `&echo` :

```
(echo set monochrome&echo $DATA ^^^<^^^<EOD&echo 1&echo 3&echo 9&echo EOD&echo plot $DATA) | gnuplot
```

This command plots values 1, 3, 9 in gnuplot with monochrome palette.

Unfortunately, maximum length of a single command is limited, therefore, this method is not applicable for large amounts of data.